# Not sure why I am getting [object Object] returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I finally was able to figure out how to remove the text from this element but save the button which was nested in it.

HTML:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal-animation">
    <p id="output">This app will go through some of your markup to determmine if it could be more accessible.  We will start by checking the alt tags on your images, seeing if they exist, or if the tags are empty!<br>
    <a id="appButtonNextChecker" class="button button-primary modal-button">lets get started!</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
EventUtility.addHandler(newBtnName, 'click', function(e) {

    var $noRemove = $('#output').find('#appButtonNextChecker'),
         text = 'flim-flam ' + $noRemove;
         console.log('next Checker, button!');

                $('#output').html(text);
});
```

I then tried to concatenate a new string with the button I saved, but to my surprise I received `[object Object]`?

I read somewhere it was a scoping issue, but I am not sure how that applies here?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `var text = 'flim-flam ' + $noRemove.html();` instead.

Comment: $noRemove is an object, not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were doing `.html( $noRemove )` that would have been fine, but the moment you want to concatenate a string, then you must get the html (string) to concatenate to the string. **You cannot concatenate a string and an object.**:

**Use**:

```
var text = 'flim-flam ' + $noRemove.html();
```

**Or**, to get all the html represented by `$noRemove` use:

```
var text = 'flim-flam ' + $('<div/>').html( $noRemove ).html();
```

Or:

```
var text = 'flim-flam ' + $noRemove[0].outerHTML;
//WARNING -- works only if $noRemove.length equals 1
```

Comment: Second option might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey that worked! But that seems strange. Could you explain what `$('<div/>').html( $noRemove ).html();` is doing? Actually it really is the `</div>`, I ask because it's not even in the `DOM` when I check it in the `developer tools`!!

Comment: `$('<div/>')` simply creates a `div` in memory; it could as well have been `<p/>` or `<span/>` or any other valid HTML tag. `<div/>` is the equivalent of `<div></div>'. The trick simply enables you to access the complete HTML of the collection/object `$noRemove`, because you append the object to the `div` in memory and then get the `innerHTM` -- via `.html()` -- of the `div`. **In short that's how you get the `outerHTML` of a DOM element in jQuery, which means that `$noRemove[0].outerHTML` should work too.

Answer (score 0):

How you want to concatenate string and button?! Do you want to get together the string and the button's value?

$noRemove is an object it is completely normal to get that message.

Comment: Great insight, but I guess that's as far as it goes?